# Как использовать core библиотеки в processing android (APDE)

Tags: android, processing

Я хочу использовать библиотеки **network** и **serial**. Написал как в примере **import processing.net.*;** в ответ говорит, что нет такой библиотеки. Я попытался ее скачать. Нажал кнопку **get libraries**. Открылся сайт https://processing.org/reference/libraries/, там список core библиотек, но ссылок на скачивание нету, есть только ссылки на скачивание библиотек сообщества.

Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо. Извините, что такой... вопрос, но я уже запарился.

Answer (score 0):

Скачал Processing3 для компьютера, от туда достал библиотеки и закачал их на телефон завернув в zip (вот бред почему нельзя было их сразу добавить в телефонную версию)